# Downloading a file from website straight to FTP server

Tags: windows, file, ftp, download, transfer

Is it possible instead of downloading a file to my computer and then uploading it to my ftp server, to download it off a website **straight** onto my ftp server? 
I've tried googling, but no result.

Comment: For this you have to instruct the FTP server to grab the file and do the downloading on its own.

Does the FTP server run an SSH daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to invoke this via CLI (command line interface) to achieve it. I don't know of any tools that allow it without using the CLI (but I'd like to stand corrected).

Options:

1. Direct FTP using DOS (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~cjensen/info/DosFtp.htm)
2. [WGET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) - Only if you SSH/login to your server in question - which will download the file directly to the server you're on, but you need to be on the server first:

> ```
> wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
> ```

I've lost count of the number of times I've done this in the past and skipped browsers...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initiate the direct connection from your FTP server to some WEB site.

But you can implement some custom downloader & uploader in order to avoid full file caching on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. open file explorer
2. left click and click on make shortcut
3. move the shortcut to desktop
4. success

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I used a web service in this week on "multcloud.com".
It could not directly download to FTP host, but you can use Google Drive as I did:

1. I used "thoaimedia.com/save" to save files in my Google Drive
2. Then, I used my WordPress website FTP account in Multcloud.
3. Also, I connected my Google Drive to Multcloud

Just three steps, then you can transfer, cut, or copy any file between your FTP host and Google Drive like two folders on your desktop.